# Using a broadcast variable in a loop in Spark with updated values

Tags: apache-spark, broadcast

I am using a broadcast variable in a loop like the following (to make it short, I show it with a kind of psudocode, not exact syntax in Java):

```
Broadcast<List<E>> brdList = jsc.broadcast(myVariable);
JavaRDD<myType> rdd = rawRdd.map(f(brdList.value()));  
List<E> updatedBrdList = rdd.map(g).collect();
brdList.unpersist();

int itr = 1000;
while (itr != 0){
   Broadcast<List<E>> brdNewList(updatedBrdList);
   rdd = rdd.map(f(brdNewList.value()));
   updatedBrdList = rdd.map(g).collect();
   itr--;
}
```

Is this usage a valid form of using broadcast variable? Does the brdNewList occupy one location in memory or in each iteration new space is occupied and a new copy is created?

With few iterations (~ <100), it works fine, but with larger iterations, it gives the following error:
[the error with using broadcast variable in Spark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMWZ9.png)

Is there any way to play around it and make it works? The value of the broadcast variable is necessary to be accessed through all nodes in each iteration.

Is this related to driver memory? or there are some computations in executors (workers)? (I am running my code on a cluster with 5 nodes.)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

"To use a broadcast value in a Spark transformation you have to create it first using SparkContext.broadcast and then use value method to access the shared value. Learn it in Introductory [Example section](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-broadcast.html#introductory-example)".

Comment: The example url is outdated.